# How to count unique values over multiple columns using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, count

Let's say I have the following df:

```
1               2                    3
home, work      work, home           home, work
leisure, work   work, home, leisure  work, home
home, leisure   work, home           home, work
```

I want to count all unique variables over the entire `data.frame` (not by columns or row, I'm interested in the cell values)

So the output should look like this:

```
                    freq
home, work          3
leisure, work       1
home, leisure       1
work, home          3
work, home, leisure 1
```

I have not found a way to do that. The `count()` function seems to work only with single columns.

Thank you very much for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `unlist` and use `table` to get count in base R :

```
stack(table(unlist(df)))
#Same as
#stack(table(as.matrix(df)))
```

---

If you prefer `tidyverse` get data in long format using `pivot_longer` and `count`.

```
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  dplyr::count(value)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  value                 n
#  <chr>             <int>
#1 home,leisure          1
#2 home,work             3
#3 leisure,work          1
#4 work,home             3
#5 work,home,leisure     1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("home,work", "leisure,work", "home,leisure"
), X2 = c("work,home", "work,home,leisure", "work,home"), X3 = c("home,work", 
"work,home", "home,work")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was very quick! thank you!:D I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm able to

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   gather %>% 
   count(value)
#              value n
#1      home,leisure 1
#2         home,work 3
#3      leisure,work 1
#4         work,home 3
#5 work,home,leisure 1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("home,work", "leisure,work", "home,leisure"
), X2 = c("work,home", "work,home,leisure", "work,home"), X3 = c("home,work", 
"work,home", "home,work")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```